# c++ double free error of different free order

Tags: c++

I meet a problem when I am testing C++.
When i am running the first code no error it throws while the second code throws "double free error". Anyone knows what is going on?

```html
Test* test1 = new Test(1);
Test* test2 = new Test(2);
delete test1;
delete test2;
delete test1;
delete test2;
```

```html
Test* test1 = new Test(1);
Test* test2 = new Test(2);
delete test1;
delete test1;
delete test2;
delete test2;
```

Comment: You're invoking *undefined behavior*, so technically *no one* knows what's going on; including your code.

Comment: @WhozCraig I see what you mean, but technically you could disassemble the program and check what it's doing, just for the hell of it.

Comment: I know it is undefined behavior, but the result keeps the same no matter how many time I run or what running environment I use. The undefined behavior seems has some regular pattern, that's what I am confusing. @WhozCraig

Comment: @yoke Did you try _compiling_ the code with different compilers? Different OSs?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yes, I've tried different compilers, still get the same result.

Comment: @yoke And what about different operating systems? In addition to that, I tried to compile the code with the first compiler that I have available on my system - MSVC. Both examples result in a crash.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yes, Mac, Windows and Linux all be tried. The first code sniff should throw error, but it doesn't at anytime while the second does.

Comment: @yoke, And, even if I try on ideone, both your examples ([first](http://ideone.com/QvaooE), [second](http://ideone.com/qhC8ZS)) succeed. I don't know what compilers you tried, but, as I already explained - no matter what I try, it results in different behavior - which is typical of undefined behavior.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius You mean you can run the second code successfully sometimes?

Comment: @yoke Did you read what I said, or clicked the links to ideone, to look at it yourself? I repeat: **both** examples, when compiled with MSVC - crash. **Both** examples when compiled on ideone (which, if I know correctly use g++) - succeed (links to those runs are in my previous comment).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Sorry for replying late, I think you are right. I just found my mistake of setting the compiler wrong. Actually different compliers do have different results. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To better understand heap usage of a program you can use valgrind on Gnu/Linux. When I run your program under valgrind I get this. Please see the summary line

> total heap usage: 2 allocs, 4 frees, 8 bytes allocated

```
valgrind ./a.out 
==7594== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7594== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7594== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7594== Command: ./a.out
==7594== 
==7594== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==7594==    at 0x4C2A360: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:507)
==7594==    by 0x40069E: main (in /home/ppm/algo/src/stackoverflow/a.out)
==7594==  Address 0x5a02040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==7594==    at 0x4C2A360: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:507)
==7594==    by 0x400686: main (in /home/ppm/algo/src/stackoverflow/a.out)
==7594== 
==7594== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==7594==    at 0x4C2A360: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:507)
==7594==    by 0x4006AA: main (in /home/ppm/algo/src/stackoverflow/a.out)
==7594==  Address 0x5a02090 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==7594==    at 0x4C2A360: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:507)
==7594==    by 0x400692: main (in /home/ppm/algo/src/stackoverflow/a.out)
==7594== 
==7594== 
==7594== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7594==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7594==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 4 frees, 8 bytes allocated
==7594== 
==7594== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7594== 
==7594== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7594== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```